# How to represent multiple parents as rewrite rule?

Tags: antlr

Say I have the following ANTLR rule:

```
ROOT: 'r' ('0'..'9')*;
CHILD: 'c' ('0'..'9')*;
expression: ROOT ('.'^ CHILD)*;
```

For input such as `r.c1.c2.c3`, ANTLR would make the following tree:

```
.(.(.(r c1) c2) c3)
```

How can I represent the parent property of `'.'` without the `^` operator directly, i.e., in a rewrite rule?

```
expression: ROOT ('.' CHILD)* -> ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to invoke the `expression` rule recursively in the rewrite rule (the `$expression` part below):

```
expression : (ROOT -> ROOT) ('.' CHILD -> ^('.' $expression CHILD))*;
```

which is equivalent to:

```
expression: ROOT ('.'^ CHILD)*;
```

Yeah, I know, it's not pretty, there is no simple syntax like you (may have) hoped for:

```
expression: ROOT ('.' CHILD)* -> ^(...);
```

See: Parr's [Definitive ANTLR Reference](http://pragprog.com/book/tpantlr/the-definitive-antlr-reference), chapter 7, paragraph *"Referencing Previous Rule ASTs in Rewrite Rules"*, page 174.

Comment: Interestingly, your approach works, but only if `ROOT` and `CHILD` are tokens and not rules. With rules, the generated code does not compile due to empty `if ( )` statements. I'm at a bit of a loss here...

Comment: @LazloBonin, as long as your parser rules produce a proper AST (1 root, 0 or more children), it should work. If not, could you edit your question with a case that fails for you?